# AsyncTask to check if user input is in database?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a problem with synchronizing results from AsyncTask when needed to check if input is vaild.

My application asks user to type in some promotion code into EditText. I want to label promotion code as valid if promotion code is in database. If promotion code entered is not in database, it is labeled as invalid.

This is code for button listener

```
        // Listens for Add button presses
    addButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String promo_code = (String) PromotCodeEditText.getText().toString();

            // Start AsyncTask that will store true or false in checkCodeInDatabase variable
            // depending if PromoCode is in database. We use checkCodeInDatabase in else if check below.
            new CheckCodeDatabase().execute(promo_code);

            // Check if Promo Code that user typed is in database
            // checkCodeInDatabase is false if course is not in database
            if (!checkCodeInDatabase) {
                // Display No code in database alert dialog
                showMsgDialog(getString(R.string.noCodeDBTitle),
                        getString(R.string.noCodeDBMessage));

                courseCodeEditText.setText("");

            } else {
                // Add promo code user typed in EditText
                addCode(promo_code);
            }
        }
    });
```

My idea is that when user presses ADD button, to add promo code, I start AsyncTask which performs a query on database. AsyncTask stores true or false in static variable checkCodeInDatabase.

Here's code for AsyncTask:

```
private class CheckCodeDatabase extends AsyncTask<String, Object, Boolean> {

    DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(MainActivity.this);

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        try {
            myDbHelper.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new Error("Unable to create database");
        }

        try {
            myDbHelper.openDataBase();
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            throw sqle;
        }

        // This returns true or false if params[0], which is a promo code,
        // is in in PromoCodes table in database.
        return myDbHelper.checkCourseInDatabase(params[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        // Store true or false in checkCodeInDatabase which is a static variable.
        // This variable will be used to check if code is valid in add button listener.
        checkCodeInDatabase = result;
        myDbHelper.close();
    }
```

**Problem:**

Problem is that AsyncTask does not store value into checkCodeInDatabase variable on time. Meaning, if statement which is performed in add button listener, value of checkCodeInDatabase is the old value because AsyncTask does not have enough time to perform database query and update checkCodeInDatabase variable before if statement is executed in add button listener.

So, how to make add button listener wait for AsyncTask to update checkCodeInDatabase and then perform if check.

Thanks in advance!

p.s. I'm new to android development. I read in some book on Android development that any queries on database should be performed in AsyncTasks, to avoid unresponsive app. Maybe it's impossible to achieve what I want with AsyncTasks. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should delegate the whole

```
        if (!checkCodeInDatabase) {
            // Display No code in database alert dialog
            showMsgDialog(getString(R.string.noCodeDBTitle),
                    getString(R.string.noCodeDBMessage));

            courseCodeEditText.setText("");

        } else {
            // Add promo code user typed in EditText
            addCode(promo_code);
        }
```

block into you AsyncTask's onPostExecute.

Doing that you are sure that you have fetched the result AND that you are running on the ui thread.